How do I use ideal MOSFET model in LTspice? or How do I set voltage in node without voltage source?
I want to simulate the principle of 1T1C DRAM cell. But if I model voltage source in Bit line, bit-line voltage is set by its input signal. So I want to seperate bit line, using ideal MOSFET component, but I cannot find ideal MOSFET model.
Question List

Is there any ideal MOSFET model in LTspice?
I want to know the way how set voltage in a node.

following is my circuit.


An ideal mosfet is modeled as:  if Vgs > Vth then Id = Vds/Rdson else Id = Vds*Goff. Or something like that. Just create a model. You set a node voltage by either tying a grounded voltage source to it (sure-fire way) or else you use the .IC card and specify it for the start of a run (but it will change over time during the .TRAN.)

Probably best to use the voltage-controlled switch for something like this.  The symbol is named sw and you need to put a SPICE directive on the schematic for the .model ... statement.  See the help page I linked for more info.  You should try to use something like Roff=1t or higher to minimize leakage when the MOSFET is off (t = tera or 1e12).
